# Load and Play Wave File (`.wav`) on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio

I created a wav file by "audacity" app on my mac and imported in MATLAB. This is the simple code I wrote to read the file. But as it reads, it plays so much slower than its actual speed. Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
d = audioread('HelloWorld.wav');
sound(d)
```

Comment: the sound function uses the default sample rate of 8kHz for playback. If your wav file sampling rate is different, your sound will be played back at  a slower (or faster) speed. There is a sound function that accepts sampling rate as an argument so you can use that function overload instead.

Comment: Also, you can get the sampling frequency of the WAV file from `audioread`. See the documentation.

Comment: A) read the documentations sound(). B) use audioplayer() . Read the documentation first there too..

Comment: @Sogol, Have you reviewed my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you load Audio file to MATLAB you basically load array of numbers.
When you play Audio there is a parameter which is needed - Sampling Rate.
This is what tells the player how fast to play the data.

Think if you load a file with 1000 samples. How long should is the audio?
Unless you supply some information, the player can not know (MATLAB just use a default which doesn't match your data).

If you look at the [documentation of the `sound()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) you'd see there is an option to use it as `sound(audioSignal, samplingRate)`.

In order to get the Sampling Rate of a Wave file use: `[audioSignal, samplingRate] = audioread(filePath)`. Read more at [`audioread()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html).